# Show column name MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to get a column name from table where all values in this column are the same!

Example! IF i would there would be a such a code it would return answer 'Works'

```
Table1
ID      Name     Works
1       Andre     Yes
2       John      Yes
3       Stewart   Yes
```

Comment: You want to know if all values in `Works` are the same? Or you want to know which columns in a table all have the same value?

Comment: @Schwern  I want to know which columns in a table all have the same value!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the columns of the table are known. If not, you could be able to get them by:

```
desc Table1;
```

or if you are using higher version of MySQL, you could use:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='your_schema' and table_name='Table1';
```

Then you try the following statement with parameters @column being replaced with the column names retrieved from the above statement:

```
select count(*) from (select count(*) as c from Table1 as t group by t.@column) as sub;
```

If the result is 1, the column is what you want. The result means how many distinct values this column has.

I suppose you will have to use a kind of programming language or stored procedure. You are not likely being able to achieve that with one single SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to run from MySQL itself but you can do this from your scripting engine.

You can run a loop on each column and do a query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) 
  FROM table_name;
```

And see you get 1 record in the results

Comment: NOTE: COUNT is incremented only for non-NULL values. If there are some rows with NULL values, and all of the other rows have the same non-null value, this will return 1. (That is, the rows with NULL values won't be counted as a separate group. And if all the rows have column value of NULL, this will return 0.